# Visual Studio 2013 - Setting up Nuget packages for every project

Tags: visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, templates, nuget

I want all of our future projects to use Bootstrap LESS and other nuget packages. Rather than supply a document to all my team members and hope they remember to set it up, am I able to create a skeleton project then template it so it appears under File -> New Project and they have the nuget packages ready to update on first build? I could set up an example Site.less to get my team started.

I'd rather have a template than circulate a solution. Is it possible to do this in VS203? The example I see don't deal with nuget packages and example code for LESS setup. They are for class setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can actually.

1. Create a new project
2. Add everything you want to it, including NuGet packages
3. Go to  <kbd>File</kbd>  =>  <kbd>Export Template</kbd>
4. Choose "Project template"
5. Fill in any information you want
6. Create a new project based on this template

[image]

If you now create this project and look at the references, you'll notice it has the NuGet packages you defined earlier. Build the project to restore the packages and you're ready to go.